# How to add File type with File icon in a listbox using c# windows Application ?

Tags: c#, winforms, registry, file-type

Eg: (fileIcon)a1.txt , (fileIcon)a2.pdf , (fileIcon)a3.pst Etc...

[image]

I have a windows form application, Actually I want to upload some files to listbox with fileIcon with file name and type. I am not getting this task! Help me out.
 Thanks....

Comment: Take a look... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108005/how-can-i-get-the-filetype-icon-that-windows-explorer-shows
and 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2532/Obtaining-and-managing-file-and-folder-icons-using

Comment: @Cadburry Is that works? As i shown in attachment?

Comment: Its not really clear what u are trying to achieve... I thought it was extracting the associated icon for a filetype.. These links are showing you how to get the icon of a given file...

Comment: Path is not required for that

Comment: Path required for what? What do you have so far.. code?

Comment: Actually if i pass the values( .txt file in a listbox means Its should show file icon with file names....

Comment: Load your filenames into your list & during loading get the associated icon by using my links and assign it to the listitem....

Comment: Okay, Thank you Cadburry!

Comment: @Cadburry it should not take file's full path, if i add fie to list box means is should only show icon+filename....

Comment: The discussion is getting too long here for my meanings...
You are merging at least 2 questions into one thread: 1rst: how to get the file icon, 2nd: how to get the Name of a file without a path - you have to post your code to let us see what you got so far...  And plz bear with me but i believe that these 2 questions have been answered many times here - plz use google and the search option in stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this line in your OpenFileDialog's Filter under its properties

```
Image File|*.jpg|Icon files|*.ico
```

and so on.. It's a set of a file type string and its extension format

```
Image File|*.jpg
```

define one type of file type supported, you can use multiple format for a file type name e.g.

```
Image Files|*.jpg,*.png,*.bmp
```

Or simply support All files by using following filter, but it is not recommended anyway

```
All Files|*.*
```

Comment: How can it supoort system icons?

Comment: It's a property of the openFileDialog.. it could be done/written in property tab. Or if you want to code it, you can try openFileDialog.Filter = "IconFile|*.ico"